# Проблема с ClassLibrary и partial class

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Использую Visual Studio Community 2015.

Создал новый проект Class Library.
Добавляю в него несколько .cs файлов.

Главный файл:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Server.API;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Server.Constant;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Server.Elements;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Server.Managers;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Shared;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Shared.Math;
using Console = Colorful.Console;

namespace Mod
{
    public partial class Mod : Script
    {
         public Mod()
         {
             Mod_Function1();
         }
    }
}
```

Остальные файлы по одному шаблону:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Server.API;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Server.Constant;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Server.Elements;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Server.Managers;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Shared;
using GrandTheftMultiplayer.Shared.Math;

namespace Mod
{
    public partial class Mod : Script
    {
        public void Mod_Function1()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("_ClientEvents");
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что функция Mod() из главного файла вызывается рекурсивно при загрузке каждого дополнительного .cs файла.

Comment: Не совсем ясно что происходит. Можете написать как Вы обращаетесь к `Mod` и что при этом идет не так?

Comment: К функции Mod() обращений нет. Она вызывается при инициализации главного скрипта. А уже из этой функции вызываются функции инициализации каждого доп. скрипта.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что означает `... вызывается рекурсивно при загрузке ...`. Что именно происходит, в чем проблема? Речь идет об обращениях к конструктору (`Mod()`) или к методу (`Mod_Function1`)?

Comment: и причем тут partiial class?

Comment: Посмотрите дерево файлов проекта, если это поможет. https://savepice.ru/full/2018/3/28/2db2a224470edac38233b9d5161459dc-full.png.html

Comment: Без partial class не видно переменные главного скрипта.

Comment: У меня был один большой скрипт Main.cs. Я поделил его на множество файлов. Каждый файл имеет функцию Mod_ххххх(). Эти функции вызываются из главного файла Main.cs из его инициализирующей функции Mod() при загрузке. Получается, что каждый из этих файлов каким-то образом вызывает функцию Mod() при загрузке и получается рекурсия. При этом поведение такое же как при var Mod = new Mod();

Comment: @ДмитрийПинчук: Ага, что-то начинает проясняться. Но вы всё же дайте нам воспроизводящий пример, а то покамест ничего не понятно

Comment: Вам 500 кб кода сюда дать? Или логи?

Comment: @ДмитрийПинчук: [mcve], пожалуйста. Чем более хороший промер вы составите, тем больше шансов, что мы поймём вашу проблему.

Comment: Я отредактировал первый пост. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Вот пример, что выдает сервер при загрузке получающегося .dll. http://www.picshare.ru/view/8648063/

Comment: т.е. поведение как-будто я создаю не partial class, а new Mod() в каждом отдельном файле, кроме главного.

Comment: @ДмитрийПинчук: Очень странно. А что если оттрассировать? Если конструктор `Mod` вызывается несколько раз, какой во второй раз стек?